# Scraping hidden jquery values using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[HERE](http://bip32jp.github.io/english/index.html) is the site I believe its hosted on GitHub.

I am having trouble scraping the values in the input fields. Specifically private key and Public. I tried using Selenium and BeautifulSoup but it would give empty values, rather None (the HTML doesn't contain the keys).

I checked the **page source** and it seems that the input value is empty (not contained within the HTML) but when you load the page it is visible and existent in the input box.

Here is my code:

```
def openit(browser):

    browser.get('file:///Users/Aha/Desktop/Code/english/index.html')
    time.sleep(5)
    nav = browser.find_element_by_id("addr")

    print(nav.text)
    return browser.page_source

soupdata = openit(browser)
soup = BeautifulSoup(soupdata, 'html.parser')
val = soup.find('input', {'id': 'addr'}).get('value')
print (val)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve that value via `execute_script` method of the `selenium webdriver`

```
print(browser.execute_script("return $('#addr').val();"))
```

**Output**:

```
14ropRunS5iY9sx9d9mpCRNEsXj7RtTtuS
```